# How to make div slide up on appearance

Tags: jquery

I know this site is built on ruby, but how can I achieve this effect in jquery the way the main content of the page slides up when you click on the appropriate link in the navigation. http://leffertsplacemews.com click on any link in the nav bar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its a jquery slider plugin viz.  **`Layerslider.`**
You can find the details HERE

http://kreaturamedia.com/layerslider-responsive-jquery-slider-plugin/

But remember one thing, its a paid plugin and you have to pay for it to use it